# Proof of Closest Point Theorem in Hilbert Space

Tags: sequences-and-series, vector-spaces, hilbert-spaces, axiom-of-choice

The theorem:

Let $C$ be a non-empty closed convex subset of a Hilbert space
$X$, and let $x \in X$. Then there exists a unique $y_0 \in C$ such that $||x-y_0|| \le ||x - y||$ all $y \in C$. In other words there is a point in $C$ which is closest to $x$.

I'm reading a proof here (https://www0.maths.ox.ac.uk/system/files/coursematerial/2014/3075/48/15B4.2-webnotes-all.pdf, p.4) and have two questions about the initial steps in the prooof (I can follow the later steps.):

1. "Let $d = inf\{||x - y||: y \in C\}$" I think that the infimum should exist by the property (axiom) of completeness of the real numbers. $\{||x - y||: y \in C\}$ is a set of real numbers which is bounded below (all norms are $\ge 0$) and therefore has a greatest lower bound - is this correct ?
2. "Let $(y_n)$ be a sequence of points in C such that $||x - y_n|| \to d$". I think such a sequence should exist by the following reasoning: With $d = inf\{||x - y||: y \in C\}$ then for any $\epsilon > 0$ there must be a point $y$ in $C$ such that $||x - y|| \lt d + \epsilon$ (otherwise $d$ is not the infimum). If for this point $||x - y|| = d $ then $y_0 = y$ and we are finished: $(y_0)$ is a one element convergent sequence. Otherwise $||x - y|| = d + \epsilon`$ where $\epsilon` \le \epsilon$ and I can repeat the process to find a **different** point where $||x - y|| \lt d + \epsilon`/2$ and so generate a convergent sequence. I'm not sure this is valid, and it occurs to me that unless $C = \{y_0\}$ there are probably an infinite number of points at each step and the Axiom of choice is then required to extract a convergent sequence. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So what part of your question is *about* the axiom of choice?

Comment: @AsafKaragila In forming the countably infinite sequence $(y_n)$ it seems to me that each $y_i$ has to be chosen from a set of points satisfying $||x - y_i|| \lt d + \epsilon$, and that in general, if this set contains two points then it contains an infinite number. So we have to select one element from each infinite set in an infinite family of sets. Does this not require AOC ?

Comment: Probably it does. But the statement is about the closure, not sequential closure.

Comment: @AsafKaragila Thanks. I'm not uncomfortable with AOC, I just hadn't previously seen any mention of dependence on it in this context.

Comment: That is because functional analysis without the axiom of choice is like intentionally cutting your thumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) You are correct. Every set that is bounded below in $\mathbb{R}$ has a least lower bound.

2)The standard why to show that there exists such a sequence $(y_n)$ is as follows. Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$ then as d is the infimium, $d+\frac{1}{n}$ is not a lower bound so there exists $y_n$ such that $d<||x-y_n||<d+\frac{1}{n}$. This gives a sequence of points $(y_n)$. Then it should be obvious that $||x-y_n||\rightarrow d$.